# Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Решил попробовать впервые написать телеграмм бота, но никак не могу преодолеть ошибку, везде искал - не помогло.
Выдает ошибку:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

```
import telebot

TOKEN = "...."
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_messange(messange):
    bot.send_messange(messange.chat.id, "Привет")


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: А через какую команду вы устанавливали библиотеку telebot?

Comment: через настройки интерпретатора в pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у Вас установлена старая версия библиотеки. Проверьте.

Актуальная версия: 3.x, возможно, у Вас установлена версия 2.3.x или ниже.

Так же возможно, Вы установили библиотеку для старой версии `pip`. Вместо `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` попробуйте `pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI`.